# Excel coding: how to categorise data and reach 1 of 3 possible outputs

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, categories

Working in Micorsoft Excel, I have a column (L3) that lists different countries, which refers to a variety of project locations, and from these projects, i want to write a piece of code that, in a new column, either categorises the projects location into Region "Sahel", Region "HoA" or leaves if blank if neither of the conditions are met.

For example:
I want countries Burkina Faso, Mali and Nigeria to be categoried as Sahel in a new column, I want just South Sudan to be categorised as Horn of Africa (HoA) and the projects listed in other countries to be returned as blank in this respective column.

What I have tried so far:

```
=IF(OR(L2="Burkina Faso";L2="Mali";L2="Nigeria"); "Sahel";"HoA")
```

-> This works for the courties I want to categories as "Sahel," however, everything else, and not just South Sudan, is then categoried as HoA, which is not what I want - But I cannot add "" at the end as I then have too many arguments in my code.

I then tried:

```
=IF(OR(L3="Burkina Faso";L3="Mali";L3="Nigeria"); "Sahel";""); IF((L3="South Sudan"); "HoA";"")
```

-> But this didn't work out at all...

**Thus the end output that I want is**

*****Countries***** Mali; South Sudan; Mali; Burkina Faso; Somalia; Uganda; South Sudan

*****For Regions*****   Sahel; HoA; Sahel; Sahel; - ; -; HoA

I hope that soneone can help me move on from here.

Comment: Please add some sample data with expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```
=IF(OR(L2="Burkina Faso",L2="Mali",L2="Nigeria"),"Sahel",IF(L2="South Sudan","HoA",""))
```

Comment: Thank you! This did the job :-D